# Независимая функция в веб приложении Java

Tags: java, servlet

Есть веб сервис на сервлетах. Нужно чтобы в приложении при запуске создавался отдельный поток(и) который делает какую то функцию.

Comment: Добавьте код точки запуска приложения

Comment: вот оно - future, такое чувство, что нейронная сеть запрашивает решение

Answer (score 1):

если архитектура приложения разрешает использовать многопоточность, то проще всего (имхо) это реализуется с помощью `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.submit()`
если же нельзя, то можно использовать например [`@Asynchronous EJB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html) если это JavaEE или его аналоги если платформа другая.